# jquery best way to bind a code snippet to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-snippets

What is the best way to bind a code snippet to a div? In few cases where some code snippet has to be dynamically binded to a dom element, what process would generally developers opt.

If we get code snippet from database, then the snippet should be displayed as it is in the div. How is that possible?

[For example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qypgs1r/):

```
$(function(){
    var myCodeSnippet="function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            console.log("drag", ev);
            ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);
        }";

        $('#test').html(myCodeSnippet);
});
```

html code

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using `html()`, use `text()` since `html()` actually attempts to render html code. http://jsfiddle.net/ymn7x8b9/

Comment: You need to escape the newlines and doublequotes inside the string.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind a code snippet to a div"? Your code just displays the code snippet in the DIV, it won't run it.

Comment: barmer, it wont display code. Code snippets will not be displayed in div with jquery.

Comment: @Chandana What is expected result ?

Comment: @Chandana: Not sure what your trying to do.. Could you please elaborate your question. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by injecting a script inside a div container.

Comment: I want to display code as a code snippet in the div.

Comment: I am trying to get code snippet from database, then the snippet should be displayed as it is in the div. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pre` element , newline `"\n"` character

```js
$(function(){
    var myCodeSnippet="function allowDrop(ev) {\n"
          + " ev.preventDefault();\n"
        + "}\n\n"
        + "function drag(ev) {\n"
        +    " console.log('drag', ev);\n"
        +   " ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);\n"
        + "}";
        $('#test').text(myCodeSnippet);
});
```

```css
pre {
  background:#eee;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 420px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<pre id="test">
</pre>
</body>
```